# How to get the factorial of a number using std :: accumulate()?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, accumulate

**Hello!**
I was using the function `std::accumulate()` to see whether it would return the factorial of 10 on applying a multiplication operation on a sequence of the natural numbers from 1 to 10, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    cout << "The factorial of 10 is " << accumulate(numbers + 1, numbers + 11,   multiplies<int>()) << "\n";"
}
```

Now I have gotten weird errors that say that the function `std::accumulate()` is not a valid operand and else (I do not remember the errors).

and as I was writing this question I tried running the code again and suddenly, the errors disappeared and all went well?

Can someone explain this weird behavior?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build-log. It will contain much more information that we need to properly know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the initial-value argument (the third argument of `std::accumulate`):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    auto numbers = std::array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::cout << "The factorial of 10 is "
              << accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),  1,  std::multiplies<int>{})
        //                                                  
              << '\n';
}
```

Note that `int` is a poor choice of arithmetic type for this computation, as the result will be larger than 32767, which is all that `INT_MAX` is guaranteed to be.  Signed integer overflow is Undefined Behaviour, so should be avoided at all costs.